# Applescript Excel 2016 open as read only

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I'm trying to get an Applescript to open a shared Excel file, but the read only function doesn't seem to work with the open alias syntax, am I doing something wrong?

Code similar to below.

```
set MasterFile to ""Macintosh HD:Users:myname:Desktop:Test File.xlsb"" as text
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate

    open alias MasterFile with read only
end tell
```

Thanks,
VD

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file, set the read only recommendation, close workbook and open again. Without setting the display alerts you'll get a prompt asking whether to open as read-only.
Cheers!

```
set MasterFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:usrname:Desktop:Test File.xlsb" as alias
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set display alerts to false
    open MasterFile
    set read only recommended of active workbook to true
    save workbook
    close active workbook
    open MasterFile
    set display alerts to true
end tell
```